# Showing react app in my HTML Javascript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-config

I have a react app and I have generated a `bundle.min.js` by creating `webapack.config.js` which looks like the following:

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/main.*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

I copied the `bundle.min.js` from the `dist\build\static\js` folder and included it in the script tag inside my HTML code `index.html` as shown below:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bundle Testing</h1>
    <p>
      Here it comes:
    </p>
    <script src="bundle.min.js"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't show my app. How should I render my app content inside this HTML code? I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: What does your react code looks like? Why don't you use a ready solution like `create-react-app` or `vite`?

Comment: I don't see a DOM container in your HTML file. You need an HTML element with an ID that your React app attaches to. From the React Docs:

Step 1: Add a DOM Container to the HTML

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: @Pete Thanks. So after adding  an HTML element ID, do I need to do something in my react app just like they are doing in `like_button.js`. How would my react app recognize the div element since I've `bundle.min.js`

Comment: @Konrad I  have generated it in some other way as well. But there are multiple `.js` files here when I ran the `yarn run build` as shown i nthe image below:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JewQf.png

Is this a better approach than going with `webpack config.js`? Is this what you were referring to using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: Yes exactly; you need to tie the two together. So your HTML file has your root div say `<div id="app" />` , and your JS creates the react component and attaches to the div: `const domContainer = document.querySelector('#div');`

Comment: @Pete The way you mentioned to tie two together makes sense. However, I'm wondering if my `bundle.min.js` is getting created using the react app, where exactly I can define something like you suggested `const domContainer = document.querySelector('#div');` ?